# How to paginate an array in a html form having submit button using will_paginate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, form-for

I have a view page `.html.erb` in rails which displays the list of attachments (pulled from array) uploaded by a particular user. This view page has a `Delete` button at the end of the page (which deletes all the attachments selected by the user). I want to paginate this page. I want the delete button to be present along with pagination. I have tried removing button and `form_for()` in this page, then pagination worked. But when i include both, it throws an error

> "undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class"

please suggest some methodology to overcome this problem.

Comment: what do you have in your form for exactly and what is in the controller action? This message is usually shown when you haven't declared your instance of a Model in the controller

Comment: controller is attachment and action is index. In the index method i retrieve all the attachments uploaded by the user to a variable @attachments_user. I will be using the same variable in the form_for as form_for(@attachments_user, :url=>'/delete') do |f|...... Using this variable i am displaying all the attachments along with check box beside each attachment for user to select items that need to be deleted. So i want this page to be deleted with delete button still existing

Comment: can you provide the code?

Comment: sorry i couldnt paste the code. Hope, i explained it clear enough

Comment: for every item you should have its own form for. Then the form for shouldn't take the argument `@attachments`, but rather you should iterate through every attachment like` @attachments.each do |attachment|` and that is the variable you should use in every form for

Comment: please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

In controller file first include the `paginate` -

```
 def index
    @orders = Order.paginate(:page => params[:page], order: 'created_at desc', :per_page => 5)
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @orders }
    end
 end
```

and in view file use as
`<%= will_paginate @order_items %>`

may this code will help to remove your errors.

Comment: i have already used all these. It works, but not with "form_for" in view pages. Please read question carefully and completely

Comment: there are already comments how was content written in form_for for access the paginate !!

Comment: could you please share some links which have answered this question